# biblatex -- remove empty parenthesis () if "number" field blank in entry of type @article

Tags: biblatex

My `.bib` file has the ff entry:

```
@article{Albertus2016,
author = {Albertus, Michael and Diaz-Cayeros, Alberto and Magaloni, Beatriz and Weingast, Barry R.},
journal = {World Development},
pages = {154--170},
title = {{Authoritarian Survival and Poverty Traps: Land Reform in Mexico}},
volume = {77},
year = {2016}
}
```

My `.tex` file has the ff in MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=chicago-authordate,
    sorting=nyt,
    natbib=true,
    maxnames=2,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{Albertus2016}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Now the output comes out with:

Albertus, Michael, et al. 2016. “Authoritarian Survival and Poverty Traps: Land
Reform in Mexico”. *World Development* 77 (): 154–170.

The empty parenthesis () is for the issue number. How can I tell LaTeX to omit the () if there is no issue number for a particular reference?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem, when I compile your MWE, I get 


Albertus, Michael, et al. 2016. “Authoritarian Survival and Poverty Traps: Land Reform in Mexico”. *World Development* 77:154–170.

Comment: Like cktai I can not reproduce the output you describe. Can you tell us your version of `biblatex-chicago` and `biblatex`? (If you don't know how to find out the versions, you can just upload the whole `.log` file for the MWE to a text-sharing site like https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/, it contains all we need to know about package versions.) I should note that usually styles from the `biblatex-chicago` package should be loaded via the wrapper package `\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}` and not via `\usepackage{biblatex}` unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: The `biblatex-chicago` package works. I didn't use it before because I had some problems.  But I am still interested to know why you could not reproduce the same results I had with `biblatex`  The `.log` file only says _This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit)_ The `BBL` file says _biblatex bbl format version 3.0_

Comment: Please post the *full* `.log` file to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/. The `.log` file will contain more detailed information about the version of `biblatex` and `biblatex-chicago` that you are using.

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned above the problem is not reproducible with current versions of the packages involved. And if there is no indication as to what package versions you are using there is no way we can say anything useful here. The question in its current form is unlikely to help future visitors with a similar issue.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. _biblatex.def_ **2018/11/02 v3.12** and _chicago-authordate.cbx_ **2018/01/11 v 3.10**... Apologies again, I'm not sure what to do after pasting it on pastebin.com, but it says that my guest paste has been posted.  And I think this is the url: [link](https://pastebin.com/9xfgieeA)

Comment: Your `biblatex` version is outdated, the current version is v3.14 (2019/12/01). I checked in my archive of historical `biblatex` versions and could not reproduce the behaviour you describe even with `biblatex` 3.12. If you are not extremely close to a tight deadline your best option is probably to update your system.